# no debugging symbols found in gdb debugger

Tags: c

When i am running my complex c programme simulator .c which include many c file in gdb it gives the error no debugging symbols found. I am using gcc -g simulator.c for compling this programme. Can any body tell me why this error is coming.

Comment: Please post a small compileable sample of your code.  Also state exactly the commands used to compile and debug it.

Answer (score 6):

You will probably will need to compile *each* .c file with -g to have a complete set of debugging symbols.

Comment: can u please give the whole command which include -f to have a complete set of debugging symbols.

Comment: @user: Er, I have no idea. You'll have to rummage around your system to figure that one out.

Comment: I have compiled each c file with -g but again it is giving the same error thai is no debugging symbols found.