# no debugging symbols found in gdb debugger

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [no debugging symbols found in gdb debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551696/no-debugging-symbols-found-in-gdb-debugger)

When I am running our complex c programme which includes many c file. It gives error "No debugging symbols found ". I am compiling each c file with gcc -g option. Still it is giving error. Can any body tell the sollution of this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could show some example lines that you are running. This might help people give better answers.

Comment: @user556761: If you have more details to add, please *edit* your original question, rather than posting a new one. It keeps down on the noise, and editing will still "bump" your question to the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are stripping the symbols? A command like the following might be the culprit:

```
strip --strip-unneeded
```

Comment: gcc -g brostub_config.c brostub_daemon.c brostub_handler. brostub_smpp_func.c brostub_vars.c build_skt.c bulk_genFile.c client client.c orascript.c orascript.pc orascript.pc_9_march_10 poly_check.c server.c simulator.c here simulator.c is the main file