# Debugging: my symbols don't get loaded in gdb?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gcc, gdb

I am working on some rather large C++ app, with most of the code being stored in a static library, and some programs that use that code.
I have what looks like a memory corruption run-time crash:

```
*** Error in `build/bin/myapp': malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x00000000021f62a0 ***
```

I want to check where that happens. GDB seems the right tool (OS: Ubuntu 14.04).

My makefiles handles both debug and release with a makefile command-line switch.

With the switch on, the `-g` flag is added and the .a library is 23.8 MB, while the app is 519 kB.
Without, its 1.6 MB and 486kB (so I'm pretty sure the debugging symbols **are** there).

My (partial) CFLAGS, as suggested by the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/debug.html):
`CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -g -Wall -O0 -fno-inline`

I run gdb with:

> gdb --args build/bin/myapp datafile.dat -a -b (...and more arguments)

My problem is that even in the debug build, gdb keeps telling me that it can't find any symbols:

> Reading symbols from build/bin/myapp...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

If I run it from within gdb, it crashes with:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff5298cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

And the `backtrace` command shows indeed that symbols are missing: frames 10 to 18 have missing information, and are probably related to my code:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5298cc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff529c0d8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff52d5394 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff53e3b28 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff52e00f7 in malloc_printerr (action=<optimized out>, str=0x7ffff53e3ec8 "malloc(): memory corruption (fast)", ptr=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4996
#4  0x00007ffff52e2e04 in _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff5620760 <main_arena>, bytes=36) at malloc.c:3359
#5  0x00007ffff52e47b0 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=36) at malloc.c:2891
#6  0x00007ffff5babe68 in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007ffff5c03e69 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x000000000045a7a5 in char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) ()
#9  0x00007ffff5c05bd6 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x000000000042df7f in ?? ()
#11 0x000000000042eef6 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000421dab in ?? ()
#13 0x0000000000422223 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000000422cfe in ?? ()
#15 0x0000000000423393 in ?? ()
#16 0x0000000000424600 in ?? ()
#17 0x000000000040fd50 in ?? ()
#18 0x000000000040566d in ?? ()
#19 0x00007ffff5283ec5 in __libc_start_main (main=0x4053c0, argc=6, argv=0x7fffffffddf8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, 
    stack_end=0x7fffffffdde8) at libc-start.c:287
#20 0x000000000040604f in ?? ()
```

I did check some of [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569855/) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551696/) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551969/) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568461/) this topic, but none of any help (most of these relate to a forgotten `-g` flag, or an added `-s`, stripping down the symbols).

**Question**: what can the next step be to find out why/where my crash happens?

Additional info:

- `gcc --version`: 5.3.0
- `gdb --version`: 7.7.1
- code dependencies: boost and opencv

Comment: did you `strip` the executable? This removes debug info.

Comment: Look at the output from `make`, it shows all commands being executed with all flags. Does it show the `-g` flag when building? It doesn't show the `-s` flag when linking? Or using the `strip` command?

Comment: Thanks guys, but every build step is logged to console, and **yes**, its perfectly fine, -g and no -s, I checked that at first (see my CFLAGS).

Comment: Ouch ! Sorry guys! Had a HARD CODED -s in my link make recipe (out of my LDFLAGS). Turns out it stripped everything!!! Fixed now, I'll probably erase this...

Comment: My makefile is ~500 lines long, I should clean that out...

Comment: Is this an optimized build (-O1, -O2, -O3)? If it is, then it is not surprising that some symbols are missing and debugging seems to execute "weird" code. For debugable results build the code with `-O0` (or just omit `-O`). That's not to say that optimized code can't be debugged - it is just _very_ hard.

Comment: Thanks @JesperJuhl, it's fixed now (see comment). For your question, my CFLAGS in the question shows that (`-O0`)

Comment: @kebs whoops - I completely overlooked that :-(

Comment: Just FYI, for memory corruption problems you will generally find the bug faster with `valgrind` than with `gdb`.

Comment: Thanks @TomTromey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but none of any help (most of these relate to a forgotten -g flag, or an added -s, stripping down the symbols).

It is *almost certain* that you either have a stray `-s` somewhere on your link line, or you run `stip` on the binary during installation.

Look at your link command line and install command carefully, there *is* strip somewhere in there.

P.S. As Tom Tromey already said, GDB is rarely effective in helping with a problem like this. Using Valgrind or Address Sanitizer will likely get you to the root cause much faster.

Comment: Thanks, as I explained in the comment, that was indeed the issue. And, yeah, Valgrind is helpful too, gdb gave me the location of the crash, but Valgrind provided a bit more info.